# Texture Paint and UV Map Islands not showing up

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I'm completely new to blender and have been following [CG Boost's beginner tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmbAs9jE1vI&list=PL3UWN2F2M2C8-zUjbFlbgtWPQa0NXBsp0&index=7).

I'm at the part where he is painting the knife blade, I already painted the handle of the knife. Unfortunately, when I select the knife blade and then switch from "Object Mode" to "Texture Paint", the UV islands I created for the knife blade don't show up in the left hand paint viewport like they do in the tutorial.

Here's a comparison:

[My Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y46U.jpg)

[Tutorial Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq3kh.png)

Notice how in the tutorial screenshot that the UV islands appear above the texture paint image in dark gray. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make sure you have "Display Texture Paint UV's" On under "View menu"

Comment: It's on, still no dice. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/LVtcF8n.png)

Comment: apply al modifiers and apply all transforms (ctrl+a)

Answer (score 2):

You must enter *Edit Mode* and select the entire object. Then UVs will appear in the *Image Editor*.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a fix, worked for me.

While on UV Tab. Tab into edit mode on geometry > select part you want to unwrap > find UV options > in the dropdown find Unwrap -> Smart UV Project.

I left the angle at 66 degrees.
Hit ok.

Unwrapped UV should appear on the white square canvas.[image]